# MIPS cannot change value in procedure

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, cpu-registers, qtspim

Hi I have this program that's supposed to find sum, min, and max out of a list of user input numbers. It works fine until I call either the blt or bgt function
At that point, qtspim turns a bunch of registers red. 
I figured, after error testing, its because I changed the register value, so I added stack space, but it still does the same thing and I've been trying things forever and nothings working.
Sorry I'm a beginner, here's my code

```
.data
intro: .asciiz "Enter integer values, one perline, terminated by a negative value.\n"
total: .asciiz "\nSum: "
minn: .asciiz "\nMin: "
maxx: .asciiz "\nMax: "
mean: .asciiz "\nMean: "

.align 2
ARRAY: .space 400
.align 2


.text
.globl main

####################################
#$s1 = input counter
#$s2 = array address

#$t1 = min
#$t2 = max
#$s6 = sum
##########################################

main:
la  $s2, ARRAY  #array address
li  $s6, 0      #sum

lui $t1, 0x7fff #min
ori $s3, $s3, 0xffff
li  $t2, 0      #max

li  $v0, 4      #ask user for numbers
la  $a0, intro
syscall


LOOP:   
    li  $v0, 5      #collect user input
    syscall

move    $s0, $v0
blt     $s0, $zero, DONE

addiu   $s1, $s1, 1 #add to counter
sw  $s0, 0($s2) #store number in array
addiu   $s2, $s2, 4 #get next array space   

add $s6, $s6, $s0   #adding total sum
blt $s0, $t1, min
bgt $s0, $t2, max


j   LOOP

DONE:
li  $v0, 4      #show sum
la  $a0, total
syscall

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $s6
syscall

li  $v0, 4      #show min
la  $a0, minn
syscall

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $t1
syscall


jr $ra


min:    addi    $sp, $sp, -4
    sw  $t1, 0($sp)
    move    $t1, $s0
    lw  $t1, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


max:    addi    $sp, $sp, -4
    sw  $t2, 0($sp)
    move $t2, $s0
    lw  $t2, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

Comment: `jr $ra` depends on the return address having been placed in `$ra`. Neither `blt` nor `bgt` do that. You need to use `jal`. If you want a conditional `jal`, place a conditional branch right before that `jal` that skips past the `jal` if the desired condition is false.

Comment: @Michael: according to http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html, even classic MIPS has `BLTZAL` and `BGEZAL` which is are conditional branch-and-link instructions.  You could use `slt` or whatever to branch-and-link on a condition other than comparing to zero.

Comment: Oops, BLTZAL and BGEZAL aren't useful on the output of `slt`, because 0 and 1 are both GE zero, and both not less than zero.  :/  Still `slt` / `sub` to create 0 or -1 might be better than conditionally-branching over a `jal`, especially if you can't fill the branch-delay slot on a real MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

As I realized you have used `blt` and `bgt` instructions to jump to labels min and max. but the problem is those are actually functions (also called procedures in mips assembly) and as you can see we have `jr $ra` at the end of both of them which sets pc (program counter register) equal to `$ra`, so you have to set `$ra` to the proper value. But don't worry. You can do it easily by using `jal "function name"`. By doing this `$ra` register will be set to the proper address which is the next line of where you have called `jal "function name"`.

```
intro: .asciiz "Enter integer values, one perline, terminated by a negative value.\n"
total: .asciiz "\nSum: "
minn: .asciiz "\nMin: "
maxx: .asciiz "\nMax: "
mean: .asciiz "\nMean: "

.align 2
ARRAY: .space 400
.align 2


.text
.globl main

####################################
#$s1 = input counter
#$s2 = array address

#$t1 = min
#$t2 = max
#$s6 = sum
##########################################

main:
jal min
la  $s2, ARRAY  #array address
li  $s6, 0      #sum

lui $t1, 0x7fff #min
ori $s3, $s3, 0xffff
li  $t2, 0      #max

li  $v0, 4      #ask user for numbers
la  $a0, intro
syscall


LOOP:   
    li  $v0, 5      #collect user input
    syscall

move    $s0, $v0
blt     $s0, $zero, DONE

addiu   $s1, $s1, 1 #add to counter
sw  $s0, 0($s2) #store number in array
addiu   $s2, $s2, 4 #get next array space   

add $s6, $s6, $s0   #adding total sum
blt $s0,$t1,L1
bgt $s0,$t2,L2
#blt $s0, $t1, min
#bgt $s0, $t2, max
L1:
    jal min
    j L3
L2:
    jal max
    j L3
L3:

j   LOOP

DONE:
li  $v0, 4      #show sum
la  $a0, total
syscall

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $s6
syscall

li  $v0, 4      #show min
la  $a0, minn
syscall

li  $v0, 1
move    $a0, $t1
syscall


jr $ra


min:    addi    $sp, $sp, -4
    sw  $t1, 0($sp)
    move    $t1, $s0
    lw  $t1, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra


max:    addi    $sp, $sp, -4
    sw  $t2, 0($sp)
    move $t2, $s0
    lw  $t2, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

I changed the `bgt` and `blt` instructions and at least it was calculating SUM well.I hope it was helpful to you.